# Unable to select scrollbar in a uib-typeahead dropdown embedded in an angular modal component

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

In my project we are using a uib-typeahead to help our users populate document fields. It is working for us just fine except when the uib-typeahead is embedded inside an angular modal component created by angular-aside. When the content for the drop-down is greater than its viewport, a vertical scrollbar appears. Used outside of a modal a user may select the scrollbar and move it up and down (our desired behaviour), but used within a modal selecting the scrollbar causes the drop-down to be dismissed and the entry at the position of the mouse becomes the chosen element (not our desired behaviour).

```
<input type="text"
       ng-model="selectedName"
       uib-typeahead="name for name in names"
       typeahead-select-on-blur="true" />
```

Using the plunkr from the dbtek/angular-aside, I've reproduced this issue in the following plunkr:

https://plnkr.co/edit/Dbth9bfshC5iEFSzqz68?p=preview

I've attempted to modify the z-index of the ul element to be greater than the z-index value of the modal, but that did not resolve the issue.

Thoughts?

Thanks in advance.